# Java Scanner useDelimiter unexpected result

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

We get 'ab' as console output when we pass the string to the scanner like this:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("a///b");
    sc.useDelimiter("/");

    System.out.print(sc.next());    
    System.out.print(sc.next());    
    System.out.print(sc.next());    
    System.out.print(sc.next());    
    sc.close();
 }
```

But if we change the scanner line to

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and pass in the same string **a///b**

The console output 'a' only. 
The console expects to input another / to output the same value.

Why do they work differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Scanner` on a `String` has reached the end of its input when it reads the `'b'` character.  But when you use a `Scanner` on `System.in`, the stream hasn't ended yet; you can still type in more input after a newline character.

If you type in `a///b` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can still type in another delimiter character `/` that will finally let the `Scanner` know that the token is finished.  If you type in `foo/`, then the next token is `"b\nfoo"`, illustrating that the `Scanner` knows that `b` is just the start of the next token, which isn't finished until another `/` arrives on the stream.

Here I've placed double-quotes around all output to display each token found, even if empty.

```
a///b    <- input; token starting with "b" is unfinished
"a"      <- output
""       <- output
""       <- output
foo/     <- input
"b       <- output
foo"     <- output
```

Comment: I realised I could also add EOF (Control + Z on windows or Control + D on mac) to finish input. Thanks!